# Variation of a scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, notation, variational-calculus

I am varying a scalar field density with the term

${\cal L}~=~-\frac{1}{2}(\partial _\mu\phi)^2$

w.r.t the scalar field $\phi$.

First of all i want to know if its true that:

${\cal L} = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)(\partial_\mu \phi)$.

Secondly i also want to show that the variation of $\cal L$ w.r.t $\phi$ gives me the equation

$\delta \phi \nabla^2\phi = -\frac{1}{2}\delta(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$.

Do i have to use partial integration of the left hand side to show this?

Reference:

1. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.011104, there the action is shown in eq. (1) and the result of the variation w.r.t $\phi$ is given in eq. (2).

Comment: $-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial_\mu\phi)$ doesn't make sense, you have the $\mu$ index down twice. The correct meaning is $-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu\phi)$ where the $\mu$ index is now summed over. See [summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: Tip: 1 question per post is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrangian:

$${\cal L} = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)(\partial_\mu \phi)$$

is not a scalar, i assume that you want the kinetic term of a scalar field:

$${\cal L_{\text{kinetic}}} = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial^\mu \phi)(\partial_\mu \phi)$$

You have to vary with respect to $\phi$

$$ δ(g^{μν}\nabla_{μ}\phi\nabla_{ν}\phi) = g^{μν}δ(\nabla_{μ}\phi)\nabla_{ν}\phi + g^{μν}δ(\nabla_{ν}\phi)\nabla_{μ}\phi  = 2\nabla_{μ}(δ\phi)\nabla^{μ}\phi$$

, then make use of Leibniz rule (integration by parts):

$$ \nabla_{μ}(δ\phi\nabla^{μ}\phi) = \nabla_{μ}(δ\phi)\nabla^{μ}\phi + δ\phi\nabla_{μ}\nabla^{μ}\phi $$

and you're there.

The action of the referenced paper also contains a potential for the scalar field coupled to the Gauss-Bonnet invariant. For that term you have to use the chain rule on $\delta(h(\phi) R^2_{GB})$

The expressions $(\partial \phi)^2$ and $(\partial^\mu \phi)(\partial_\mu \phi)$ are equivalent.

Comment: Could you tell me why the ${\cal L_{\text{kinetic}}}$ term is called kinetic term? Is it just because it looks like the usual kinetic energy term from quantum mechanics?

Comment: Yes, it's basically the kinetic energy of the scalar field. No need to overthink it, remember that in classical mechanics the Lagrangian for a of a particle moving in an arbitrary potential is $L = T-V = \cfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 -V$.